# How to set a pointer to be invalid?

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree, nodes

I've coded a binary search tree and made a function which deletes a node. 
Generally it has two input parameters the first is a pointer which points to the object which needs to be deleted and the second one points on the root of the binary search tree.

Basicly all my cases work, besides the "easiest" one where the node is a leaf.

My Code sets the content of the node which is supposed to be deleted to 0, however there is still a reference to this and it's showed in the tree.

*p is the Element which is supposed to get deleted.

*pBaum points to the root of the tree.

*p-> right and *p->left are pointers to right and left subtrees of *p.

*p->conten is the value of *p.

My Code in the leaf case:

```
struct tnode  *deletenode(struct tnode *p, struct tnode *pBaum) 
{
    if (p !=NULL)
    {

        if ((p->left == NULL) && (p->right == NULL)) 
        {
        printf("%d Ist Blatt \n", p->content);
        free(p);
        return pBaum;
        }
```

Basicly i "only" need to tell the pointer *p that its from now on invalid. However i cant manage to find a proper solution. Maybe you guys can help.

EDIT: Ok i've tried it on my own to set the parent pointer to NULL.

```
struct tnode* danglingPointerFix (struct tnode *p, int nodtodelete)
{
 if((p->right)->content = nodtodelete)
    {
        p->right = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
    if((p->left)->content = nodtodelete)
    {
        p->left = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
}

struct tnode *searchnode(struct tnode *p, int nodtodelete) 
{
if (p == NULL)
{
    printf("Baum ist leer oder Element nicht vorhanden \n");
    return 0;
}
if ( p -> content == nodtodelete)
{
    return p;
}
if (p->content < nodtodelete)
{
    danglingPointerFix(p, nodtodelete);
    return searchnode (p->right, nodtodelete);
}
if (p->content > nodtodelete)
{
    danglingPointerFix(p, nodtodelete);
    return searchnode(p->left, nodtodelete);
}
}
```

However im segfaulting, maybe somewhere can see where because in my opinion this solution should work.

Comment: Is there a reason why setting the pointer to NULL isn't a viable option? But perhaps you're looking at this the wrong way. Usually when maintaining a tree such as this you'd set the pointers of the left and right nodes so they would no longer refer to the deleted node.

Comment: aren't you forgetting the references to `p`?

Comment: 0XDEADBEEF is sometimes used to mark a pointer as invalid

Comment: @BobJarvis I've tried it and it didnt work. The problem is *p is a pointer to the node but it doesnt tell the p-> right or p->left pointer from the previous node that its invalid.

Comment: @Cornstalks: I was just in the midst of editing my comment to try to lead OP gently in that direction.

Comment: This probably isn't just a problem for leaf nodes. For both non-leaf and leaf nodes you need a way to inform the parent node that the node has been deleted (that is, set `parent->left` or `parent->right` to `NULL`, depending on whether `p` is the left or right child of the parent). There's no simple way around this: you need to modify the parent node to clear out the dangling reference.

Comment: @BobJarvis i've included the searchnode function do you know where i need to modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to find the parent node pointing to the leaf you want to delete. When found you should set the corresponding `left` or `right` pointer in the parent to `NULL`.

So your delete should look like:

```
struct tnode  *deletenode(struct tnode *p, struct tnode *pBaum) 
{
    if (p !=NULL)
    {

        if ((p->left == NULL) && (p->right == NULL)) 
        {
            // This is a leaf --> It may be deleted
            deleteNodeInParent(pBaum, p);

            printf("%d Ist Blatt \n", p->content);
            free(p);
            return pBaum;
        }
```

Then you need to implement the `deleteNodeInParent`. It will be much like your current search function except that you'll check whether `left == p` or `right == p` and - if it does - set the value to `NULL` and return.

Something like:

```
void deleteNodeInParent(struct tnode *p, struct tnode *pDeleted) 
{
    if (p == NULL)
    {
      printf("Baum ist leer oder Element nicht vorhanden \n");
      return;
    }
    if (p->left == pDeleted)
    {
        p->left = NULL;
        return;
    }
    if (p->rigth == pDeleted)
    {
        p->rigth = NULL;
        return;
    }

    if ( p -> content == pDeleted->content )
    {
      // Can only happen for head - just return
      return;
    }
    if (p->content < pDeleted->content )
    {
      deleteNodeInParent(p->right, pDeleted);
      return;
    }
    if (p->content > pDeleted->content )
    {
      deleteNodeInParent(p->left, pDeleted);
      return;
    }
}
```

That said, I think it will be much easier if you extended the struct tnode with a pointer to parent.

Comment: i've tried something on my own its pretty simliar maybe you can see the segmentation fault in my danglingPointerFix method.

Comment: @RobinSchmidt - well, you do an assignment `=` instead of a test `==` in your `danglingPointerFix ` function. I'm not sure whether that leads to a segmentation fault. But fix that first.

Comment: @RobinSchmidt - also you must check for `p->right == NULL` before doing `if ((p->right)->content ...` because all you know is that `p`isn't `NULL` but both `p->left` and `p->right`maybe `NULL`

Comment: @RobinSchmidt - your approach seems a little strange as the search function may **never** be called for anything else than deleting a node. That's not what I would expect from a `searchnode` function.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have freed the leaf node, the parent node still keeps the dangling pointer.

One way of solving it is to add the following functions:

```
struct tnode  *deleteLeftNode(struct tnode *parent, struct tnode *pBaum) {

    if (parent) {
        deletenode(parent->left, pBaum);
        parent->left = NULL;
    }
    return pBaum;
}

struct tnode  *deleteRightNode(struct tnode *parent, struct tnode *pBaum) {

    if (parent) {
        deletenode(parent->right, pBaum);
        parent->right = NULL;
    }
    return pBaum;
}
```

Comment: i've tried something on my own its pretty simliar maybe you can see the segmentation fault.

Comment: If the right node `NULL` and you try to remove the left node it will crash. And you need `==` to make a comparison. (single `=` is assignment).  Try `if(p->right && (p->right)->content == nodtodelete)`